# Adding CSS Class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Below I have included the jquery code I am using to add a css class to the link in the side column that equals the active url, but it's not working, and at some point it did.

Link: http://www.liquidcomma.com/portfolio/project/TSF_Robot_Ad/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("ul.right_submenu > li > a").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("href") == location.href)
            {
                  $(this).addClass("CurrentProject");
            });
};
</script>
```

Comment: I guess the issue is here: $(this).attr("href") == location.href - one of the urls may be normalized / resolved

Answer (score 5):

Well, besides that code missing braces and parens it can be done much simpler:

```
$(function(){
    $("a[href^='" + location.href + "']").addClass("CurrentProject");
});
```

Comment: I've made a change to address Miguel's concern, the '^=' in the selector will now only match href's that begin-with the current location URL.

Comment: Exchange ^= with $= .. Begins with and Ends with respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You have unclosed braces in your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.right_submenu > li > a").each(function() {
        var a = $(this);
        if (a.attr('href') == location.href) {
            a.addClass("CurrentProject");
        }
    });
});
```

and you could rewrite your script like this:

```
$('ul.right_submenu > li > a[href=' + location.href + ']')
    .addClass('CurrentProject');
```

Comment: Hi,

If you go to liquidcomma.com and you see the Case Studies section I tried the shorter code you provided as an alternative solution, but it nothing seems to be happening. This is strange since both example you provided seem to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Following your link, my `location.href` goes to `http://www.liquidcomma.com/portfolio/project/TSF_Robot_Ad/1/` but your project link in the page points to `http://www.liquidcomma.com/portfolio/project/trade_show_fabrications/1`... that will make `attr('href') != location.href`.

In the other links, `location.href` will be ending with a slash whereas the link's `href` will not.

You should use something else to match your project other than the `href` attribute, if you expect it to change in the future (and it probably will).