# How to add a class in a div somewhere else in the DOM with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can add class `.jokjok` in the `div` next of `input[bdate]`?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/cLNJE/1/

This code did not work for me:

```
<button>Click Me</button>
<div class="pa_row mediumCell">
    <div class="column">
        <input type="text" name="expass">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="auto_box2">
            <input type="text" name="bdate">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <input type="text" name="old">
    </div>
</div>



$('button').live("click", function () {
    $('input[bdate]').closest('.pa_row ').find('auto_box2 div').removeClass().addClass('jokjok');
    //alert('click is ok')
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding CSS Class using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657787/adding-css-class-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to specify which attribute you want to use for selection  of the right input:

```
$('input[name="bdate"]');
```

This worked for me:

```
$('button').live("click", function () {
    $('input[name="bdate"]').closest('.pa_row').find('div.column div.auto_box2 div').first().removeClass().addClass('jokjok');
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/cLNJE/7/

Answer (score 0):

the easy ways is:
Add id attribut to div

```
<div id="someid"></div>
$('button').live("click", function () {
    $('#someid').addClass('jokjok');
});
```

Or

Create new whole div

```
$('button').live("click", function () {
        $('input[name="bdate"]').after('<div class="jokjok"></div>');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your selectors are not quite right,

```
$('input[bdate]')
```

should be

```
$('input[name=bdate]')
```

this will select the input with a name attribute of 'bdate' your previous selector was selecting all inputs that had an attribute of 'bdate'

```
find('auto_box2 div')
```

should be

```
find('div.auto_box2')
```

this will select the 'div' with a class of 'auto_box2'

Making those changes leaves us with this code -

```
$('button').live("click", function() {
    $('input[name=bdate]').closest('.pa_row ').find('div.auto_box2').removeClass().addClass('jokjok');
    alert('click is ok')
});
```

which should hopefully do what you want.

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/542ZW/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/cLNJE/8/

```
$('button').live("click", function () {
    $('.auto_box2 input').siblings('div').addClass('jokjok');
});
```